# Programmatically delete a widget on home screen by click listener in android

Tags: android, database, android-widget, homescreen

I've a widget which I would like to delete programmatically if the user gives the command by clicking on some button or so. But as per my knowledge the app programme and the widget programme will be running in different processes. So how is it possible to get the control of another process remote view and delete the same clearing all the db contents related to the widget?

Answer (score -2):

If you are developing both app and widget then you can send intent to the app and remove widget when intent is received.